# How do I change the titles of the select options, but keep the values the same?

Tags: angularjs

So I have an simple array `values = [0, 1]` and it will be supplied to

```
<select ng-model="myValue" ng-options="v for v in values "></select>
```

After this, i will have a dropdown list having two options: `0` and `1`.

But what I want are:

1. In the web page, I don't want to show `0` or `1`, but `false` and `true`.
2. Once a user select an option (either `false` or `true`), the real model `myValue` should be `0` or `1`, not `false` or `true`.

How can I do this?

Comment: @Blackhole what if `when v == "", then should stay ""` I mean the options for `values` have an extra `empty` one.

Comment: @Blackhole could you pls simply transform your comment to an answer? Yours is best for my needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation for `ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#usage), you can use an expression of the form `select as label for value in array`, in which `label` can be **any correct AngularJS expression**. You can use, for instance:

```
<select
    ng-model="myValue"
    ng-options="value as (value ? 'true' : 'false') for value in values"
></select>
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Blackhole/5k5mujzy/)</kbd>

This can be acceptable when you have just a few number of possible values, but it becomes quickly unreadable if your array grows larger:

```
<select
    ng-model="myValue"
    ng-options="value as (value === 1 ? 'true' : value === 0 ? 'false' : value === -1 ? 'undefined') for value in values"
></select>
```

In such a case, I strongly advise you to use an object, as suggested by [David Barker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28484527/2057033).

Answer (score 2):

Flat array initialisation won't let you do this with standard ng-options as the label is the first part of the ng-options initialisation.

```
ng-options="label for v in values"
```

To do this properly, your options would be better formatted like so:

```
$scope.values = [
    { label : 'true', value: 1 },
    { label : 'false', value: 0 }
];
```

This would allow you to define the option label from the object in the for loop

```
<select ng-model="myValue" ng-options="v as v.label for v in values"></select>
```

If you want/have to stick with your current setup you could do something along the lines of:

```
var initialValues = [0,1];

$scope.values = [];

// Assuming ES5
initialValues.forEach(function(value, index)
{
    $scope.values.push({
        label : (!!value).toString(),
        value : value
    });
});
```

And modify the HTML to be as above.

Comment: You probably mean `ng-options="v.value as v.label for v in values"`, don't you?